# Reading from the Console using the While Statement

Tags: c++, user-input, while-loop

In the code below, `cin` only extracts non-blank characters, so I can easily work out the number of input characters, upper case, etc... that is enetered by the user, easily ignoring the blanks.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    int numberOfNonBlanks = 0;
    int numberOfUpperCase = 0;
    char c;
    while ( cin >> c )
    {
        ++numberOfNonBlanks;
        if ( ( c >= 'A' ) && ( c <= 'Z' ) )
        {
            ++numberOfUpperCase;
        }
    }
    cout << "Non blank characters: "  << numberOfNonBlanks << endl
         << "Upper case characters: " << numberOfUpperCase << endl;

    system( "PAUSE" );
}
```

My question is, what consitutes `no input`? I mean using `while ( cin >> c )` I receive the user input characters and count the number of whatever, but until when?  When would it stop?  What would qualify as `no input` for the while loop to exit?

Thank you,

Comment: I guess the language tag is missing ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until you get the EOF character.

If you std input is comming from the keyboard:

- On Windows hit ctrl^Z
- On Unix hit ctrl^D

If the OS is redirecting a file to the standard input then it will happen at the end of the file normally.